# Hijack ones contact?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

I received an email that has bunch of people's email addresses in it, and I want to contact one of them but have not had that person's email address before. If I send an email to him, can I say

> Sorry I hijacked your contact from the email.

or it would sound weird? It's a friendly email (not business) but I just want to convey that I know I have not had your email before but this is how I got it and am transparent about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that doesn't work.

Like "steal", "hijack" can certainly be used in a light-hearted way, but it has the implication of taking control of something and taking it in a different direction. So you could hijack a conversation, a party, a trip. But it doesn't fit for taking somebody's contact details.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds a little too strong for the given situation. I'd recommend changing the verb *hijack* to something a bit less severe, like *found, took,* or *grabbed*:

> I hope you don't mind that I grabbed your email address from that other email.
>
> I found your contact info on another email; I hope that's okay.